# the path of vs the path to

Tags: prepositions

Is there a difference between "the path of something" and "the path to something"? I'm confused.

Here are two examples:

1. The paths **of** spiritual life growth (1): Be Quiet Before God and Pray With a Single-minded and Sincere Heart
2. The paths **to** spiritual life growth (1): Be Quiet Before God and Pray With a Single-minded and Sincere Heart

Comment: In your opinions, are the prepositions used correctly in the two examples above?

Comment: Even if they are interpreted as giving different meanings to the sentence, they are both grammatical. But if by *correct* you mean more than just grammatical, I can't answer that without knowing exactly what the sentence is trying to express. As I said, it doesn't appear in this sentence as if it matters which is used. But it's possible it might; the entire passage within which the sentence appears would need to be considered.

Comment: Consider the difference between "path of least resistance" and "path to least resistance".

Answer (score 1):

'*Path to*' indicates the way to get to something, the direction you would take to get to it. (eg the route you take to get to the top of a mountain)

> Path to the iceberg

This would explain the route (or the steps) you take to get to the iceberg

This is sometimes also metaphorical (path to enlightenment/salvation)

> The path to salvation requires you to do (x) before you can start upon it

---

"Path of" indicates where a particular something itself is going to or has been (like the trajectory of a planet)

> Path of the iceberg

This tells you where the iceberg is going (or has been)

This could also be metaphorical, but would mean the direction you take to stay on the path of enlightenment/salvation

> The path of enlightenment is fraught with temptation

---

As Jason says in comments - for metaphorical use, it might not matter which one is used.

Answer (score 0):

"Path to" refers to someone or something on a journey. for example, The militant crew will follow the path to the riverside road. However, Path of refers to the path someone has already made. like the dull student is following the path of bright student to get success in the examinations.

Answer (score 0):

The object of *path to* is the ***destination***.  The object of *path of* is the ***thing taking or defining the path***. 
For example in the “the path to the store” *store* is the destination.  In “the path of the plane”, *plane* is what’s following the path.  “path (or way) of” can also be used to name a path because it names a defining characteristic of the path.

In “path to spiritual life growth”, spiritual life growth is the goal. If one is successful they will attain spiritual life growth.  If that is the intent then use that one.   In “path of spiritual life growth”, spiritual life growth is what is a defining characteristic of the path.  It is what is experienced while on the path. I.e., take this path and you will experience spiritual life growth.

Use whichever one meets your intent.

Comment: The two examples above are titles of a series of posts on a Facebook. These posts tell us three paths to help us grow in our spiritual life.  The example is one of them.